# Is it possible to call/use instance attributes or global variables from a custom loss function using Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I would like to define a loss function like the following:

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    calculate loss based on y_true, y_pred and self.list_of_values
```

where variable self.list_of_values is modified outside this function every iteration and therefore, will have different values each time the custom_loss_function is "called". I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653015/how-do-i-call-a-global-variable-in-keras-custom-loss-function-to-change-the-ret) that the loss function is called only once, and then "a session iteratively evaluates the loss".

My doubt is whether it is possible to work with global/external variables (with dynamic values) from the loss function that is then used like this:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss_function, optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124158/keras-loss-function-with-additional-dynamic-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in Comments Section, for the **benefit of the Community**.

The Variable, `list_of_values` can be considered as an `Input Variable` like

`list_of_values = Input(shape=(1,), name='list_of_values')` and define the `Custom Loss function` as shown below:

```
def sample_loss( y_true, y_pred, list_of_values ) :
    return list_of_values * categorical_crossentropy( y_true, y_pred )
```

Also, the same `Global Variable` can be passed as an Input to the Model like:

```
model = Model( inputs=[x, y_true, list_of_values], outputs=y_pred, name='train_only' )
```

Complete code for an example is shown below:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy

def sample_loss( y_true, y_pred, list_of_values ) :
    return list_of_values * categorical_crossentropy( y_true, y_pred ) 

x = Input(shape=(32,32,3), name='image_in')
y_true = Input( shape=(10,), name='y_true' )
list_of_values = Input(shape=(1,), name='list_of_values')
f = Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same')(x)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same')(f)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(f)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Flatten()(f)
y_pred = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='y_pred' )(f)
model = Model( inputs=[x, y_true, list_of_values], outputs=y_pred, name='train_only' )
model.add_loss( sample_loss( y_true, y_pred, list_of_values ) )
model.compile( loss=None, optimizer='sgd' )
print model.summary()
```

For more information, please refer this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127646/13465258).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!